# Login PHP => SQL Server

Tags: sql, php5, sql-server-2014

aca tengo un problema ya tengo conectada la bd sql server con php y ahora quiero hacer la consulta de los registros para cuando haga match las credenciales entre y si no, no entre, pero no me funciona el codigo, me muestra este error en el dom

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\MIDAS\log.php on line 22

Este es mi codigo:

```
<?php
$username = $POST['usuario'];
$password  = $_POST['pass'];
if(empty($_POST['usuario']) || empty($_POST['pass'])){
    echo "Fill all the fields!";
}
else{
$tsql = "SELECT * FROM CatUsuarios WHERE U_UsdName='$username' AND U_Password='$password' LIMIT 1"; }
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $con, $tsql, array(), array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET ));
while($Row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt))
if($stmt == true){
    $_SESSION['valid_user'] = true;
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $username;
    header('Location: index.php');
    die();
}else{
    header('Location: error.html');
    die();
}

?>
```

Si alguien me puede ayudar o algo, se lo agradezco de ante mano

Comment: $username =$POST['usuario'] debe estar así $username =$_POST['usuario']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que te faltan agregar las llaves a tu while y tu primer $_POST[] le hace falta el guion bajo

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['usuario'];
$password  = $_POST['pass'];
if(empty($_POST['usuario']) || empty($_POST['pass'])){
    echo "Fill all the fields!";
}
else{
    $tsql = "SELECT * FROM CatUsuarios WHERE U_UsdName='$username' AND U_Password='$password' LIMIT 1";
}
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $con, $tsql, array(), array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET ));
while($Row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)){
    if($stmt == true){
        $_SESSION['valid_user'] = true;
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $username;
        header('Location: index.php');
        die();
    }else{
        header('Location: error.html');
        die();
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: usuario in C:\xampp\htdocs\MIDAS\log.php on line 2

Notice: Undefined index: pass in C:\xampp\htdocs\MIDAS\log.php on line 3
Fill all the fields!
Notice: Undefined variable: tsql in C:\xampp\htdocs\MIDAS\log.php on line 10
Logo

Comment: Te aparecen esos errores o a que se debe el comentario?

Comment: Así es o tu crees que de plano el codigo esta para rehacerlo? y si es asi, tienes algun ejemplo?

Comment: No tanto rehacerlo, solo una modificación. Por lo que entiendo, esos errores se deben a que no existen las variables `$_POST['usuario']` y `$_POST['pass']` al momento de que las asignas, lo que tienes que hacer es colocarlas después de la comprobación que haces con `empty()` osea, en el bloque del `else`

Answer (score 0):

parece que el problema esta en un error de sintaxis al definir $_POST['usuario'] `$username = $POST['usuario'];`

ya que deberia ser de la siguiente manera:

```
$username = $_POST['usuario'];
```

tu while esta de mas ya que solo puedes verificar si encontró ese usuario y contraseña, no necesitas el while si no requieres acceder a la información resultante con solo saber si lo encontró o no

```
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $con, $tsql);
if($stmt == true){
    $_SESSION['valid_user'] = true;
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $username;
    header('Location: index.php');
    die();
}else{
    header('Location: error.html');
    die();
}
```

Comment: No lo vi, lo movi al editar el codigo aqui en stack, lo corregi, pero el error permanece

Answer (score 0):

Saludos al parecer tienes varios errores en tu código  si te fijas en el **$_POST** tienes algo así:

```
$username = $POST['usuario'];
```

Cuando deberia ser así:

```
$username = $_POST['usuario'];
```

adicional también tienes un error en el **while** lo tienes definido así:

```
while($Row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt))
if($stmt == true){
    $_SESSION['valid_user'] = true;
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $username;
    header('Location: index.php');
    die();
}else{
    header('Location: error.html');
    die();
}
```

podemos notar que no tiene o no indicas el inicio ni el fin del mismo puedes hacerlo algo así:

**Usando llaves:**

```
$i = 1;
while ($i <= 10) {
    echo $i++; 
}
```

**sin llaves:**

```
$i = 1;
while ($i <= 10):
    echo $i;
    $i++;
endwhile;
```

por el resto parece estar bien para mayor detalle del while puedes revisar la documentación oficial: [while PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.while.php)

Espero te sirva y suerte..!!